# Substrate - Generating Transaction History of a Wallet

Tags: extrinsic, transactions, substrate-archive, archive, wallet

How can I generate transaction history of a wallet?

I was able to run [substrate-archive](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-archive) alongside polkadot and a template node in archive node. I stored onto postgres: state_traces, blocks, extrinsics, metadata, and storage. Additionally, is there an easier way to do this?

I thank this community for their support.

Comment: Can you define easier? You could of course use an existing block explorer like https://www.subscan.io/ which provides a REST endpoint for getting this information... however, to generate it yourself, you will basically need an archive of all the data like what `substrate-archive` provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`substrate-archive` is very raw to iterate chain's kv db and generate block/extrinsics, need some processor/etl tool to extract info you want.   except for `subscan` the api service Shawn mentioned, you may also consider `subquery` which is a framework allow you customize the process flow